# How do I get the Index of a key in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

So I have a `Dictionary` like so:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int,string>();
dictionary.Add(10,"Element 1");
dictionary.Add(20, "Element 2");
dictionary.Add(35, "Element 3");
```

Now I would like to get the `index` of the element where the key is `20`

Initially I thought:

```
dictionary.Keys.IndexOf(20);
```

but apparently this doesnt exist. So is what I'm looking to do possible?

To clarify: I don't want to return the `Value` ("Element 2") where the key is `20` Instead I would like to return the `Index` based on where the items were inserted i.e. Where key = `20` the index would be `1`

Comment: A dictionary has no index since it's not an ordered collection.

Comment: Use it like an array. `dictionary[20]` will give you "Element 2"

Comment: You probably want a [SortedList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.collections.sortedlist(v=vs.110).aspx) instead

Comment: @DodgerThud I don't want to return `Element 2` I want to return `2`

Comment: `dictionary[20]` is a key lookup not an index lookup

Comment: you can't with a dictionary. it doesn't have any sense. Elements aren't sorted and the "index" is the key, containing the value.

Comment: win for @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Timschmelter.. my bad

Comment: Sounds like you want OrderedDictionary.

Comment: Linq: `dictionary.Keys.Select((v, i) => new {Value = v, Index = i}).Where(item =>  item.Value == 20).Select(item => item.Index);`

Comment: Are you wanting to know the "index" based on what order the keys were _added_ or on the actual order of the key - meaning if they were added in this order: 10, 30, 20 - would you expect the index of 20 to be `1` (2nd item) or `2` (3rd item)?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: then the dictionary is modified and the old index is wrong. You can't rely on the order of dictionary entries. So don't write code that relies on it.

Comment: @D Stanley I was looking for the index they were added

Comment: @user1: if it's important either use a different collection like `OrderedDictionary` or store the insertion order yourself in another collection. Otherwise you can't rely on it, f.e. if you delete items the indexes will not be the same.

Comment: Tim is right; this is not a service the dictionary guarantees to provide, so you must not rely on it. If you need to know what order items were added and removed from a dictionary then maintain another data structure -- a queue, say, -- off to the side. Or implement your own dictionary type; it's not that hard.

Comment: @TimShmelter good point. I am using a `PCL` so it doesnt look like `OrderedDictionary` is available to me unfortunately

Comment: OrderedDictionary does not do what you want; it maintains the *keys* in order *by key*, not *by time added*.

Comment: Why not just use something other than a string as a value for the dictionary? Like a Class that holds the string and the index.

Comment: @user1: you should also clarify your requirement in your question. Is it really the insertion order or is it the index according to the value of the key in which case an `OrderdDictionary` would be an option? You now know that "index" is not sufficient because a dictionary has no index.

Comment: Just a quick observation, If dictionaries arent indexed. How do they support `ElementAt(index)`?

Comment: @user1: that an extension method of the `Enumerable`-class which can be used because dictionary implements `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`. But it doesn't change the fact that you can't rely on the order. You can enumerate a dictionary. But the order could be different every time.